# Copying excel charts to ppt with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple pivot graphs from excel sheet to a new ppt.

Below is the code I have tried. But, in this code after pasting the first graph it is throwing error and Power point is also crashing.

```
Sub ClickPpt()

      'Declare the needed variables
    Dim newPP As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim currentSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim Xchart As Excel.ChartObject
     'Check if PowerPoint is active
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Set newPP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Open PowerPoint if not active
    If newPP Is Nothing Then
        Set newPP = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
    'Create new presentation in PowerPoint
    If newPP.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPP.Presentations.Add
    End If
    'Display the PowerPoint presentation
    newPP.Visible = True
    'Locate Excel charts to paste into the new PowerPoint presentation
    For Each Xchart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
     'Add a new slide in PowerPoint for each Excel chart
        newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set currentSlide = newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPP.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

    'Copy each Excel chart and paste it into PowerPoint as an Metafile image
        Xchart.Select
        'ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        'currentSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
        ActiveChart.Parent.Copy
        currentSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    'Copy and paste chart title as the slide title in PowerPoint
        'currentSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

    'Adjust the slide position for each chart slide in PowerPoint. Note that you can adjust the values to position the chart on the slide to your liking
        newPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 25
        newPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 150
        currentSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 250
        currentSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 500

    Next

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set currentSlide = Nothing
Set newPP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can someone help me with the code or provide me some code to do this process?

Comment: What's the error message, and on what line?

Comment: Error message is Run-time error: '-2147023170(800706be)' - Automation Error: The remote procedure call failed. The error is inside the for loop somewhere because each time I run its changing the line inside the foor loop only.

Comment: I might have time later to look into this in more detail, but at a first glance, the `currentSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select` looks suspect - I'd avoid using `Select` (and `Selection` later on). Also the hard-coded `2` in `currentSlide.Shapes(2)` might be a red flag.